# Como fazer um print formatado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Olá. Desculpa a pergunta tão básica, mas comecei a mexer com python tem 1 semana.
Estou escrevendo um programa que grava os votos de candidatos em um arquivo binário. Mas, na hora de exibir não estou encontrando uma forma de deixar "bonito". Gostaria que aparecesse apenas o Nome e a Quantidade de votos. Segue código:

```
arquivo = open('C:\Users\Cassio\Documents\Python Programs\eleicao.dat', 'rb')
    print ('Os votos dos candidatos serao exibidos a seguir: ')
    for x in range(cont):
        aux = pickle.load(arquivo)
        print('O candidato(a): ', aux['NOME'], 'tem: ', aux['NUM_VOTOS'], 'votos.')
    arquivo.close()
```

Segue a saída do código:

```
Os votos dos candidatos serao exibidos a seguir: 
('O candidato(a): ', 'CASSIO', 'tem: ', 50, 'votos.')
```

Gostaria que fosse exibido sem as aspas e parenteses. Desde já agradeço.

EDIT: consegui resolver de uma forma meio "grotesca", mas que funciona. Segue código:

```
print'Candidato(a): '+aux['NOME']+' - '+str(aux['NUM_VOTOS'])+' votos\n'
```

Saída:

```
Candidato(a): CASSIO - 300 votos
```

Answer (score 0):

Poderia utilizar a função [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (retro-compatível com python 2.6+).

```
print('O candidato(a): {} tem {} votos.'.format(aux['NOME'], aux['NUM_VOTOS']))
```

Uma versão compatível apenas para (Python 3.6+) seria utilizando a sintaxe de [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) em python:

```
print(f'O candidato(a): {aux["NOME"]} tem {aux["NUM_VOTOS"]} votos.')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!